# Suggestion of how to avoid using a temporary variable

Tags: javascript

The `getLanguageCodeIndexPosition` function finds the position of the language code in the tokens of a url, I would like to avoid the temporary `position` variable, perhaps a more functional solution.

I don't know if the language token will be `en` or`es`, so I look for both if one is found returns its position

I welcome your suggestions

```
const languages = ["en", "es"];
const path = "http://www.app.name.local/es/compass/sample-compass/compass-temporal";

function getLanguageCodeIndexPosition() {
    const tokens = path.split("/");
    let position = undefined;

    languages.forEach(sef => {
        const index = tokens.findIndex(token => token === sef);

        if (index !== -1) {
            position = index;

            return false;
        }
    });

    return position;
}

const position = getLanguageCodeIndexPosition();

console.log(position);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you plan on doing with this index value?

Comment: It is part of a component to change the language of the site, when the user clicks on one of the languages provided on the site, I need to replace the language code in the url, this function identifies where the url tokens will be placed the language code that the user selected, after that call `location.replace (newuri)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the function under `findIndex`:

```js
const languages = ["en", "es"];
const path = "http://www.app.name.local/es/compass/sample-compass/compass-temporal";

function getLanguageCodeIndexPosition() {
    const tokens = path.split("/");
    return tokens.findIndex(token => languages.includes(token));
}

console.log(getLanguageCodeIndexPosition());
```

Comment: This is nice. Might as well make it a one-liner and get rid of the `tokens` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first matching language index with `map()` and `find()`.

```js
const languages = ["en", "es"];
const path = "http://www.app.name.local/es/compass/sample-compass/compass-temporal";

function getLanguageCodeIndexPosition() {
    const tokens = path.split("/");
    return languages
      .map(lang => tokens.indexOf(lang))
      .find(i => i >= 0);
}

const position = getLanguageCodeIndexPosition();

console.log(position);
```

You can also use the `reduce()` method to get an array of all language indexes.

```js
const languages = ["en", "es"];
const path = "http://www.app.name.local/es/compass/sample-compass/compass-temporal";

function getLanguageCodeIndexPosition() {
    const tokens = path.split("/");
   
    return languages.reduce((acc, lang) => {
      const i = tokens.indexOf(lang);
      return i >= 0 ? [...acc, i] : acc;
    }, []);
}

const position = getLanguageCodeIndexPosition();

console.log(position);
```

Comment: Nice solution in `map` an `filter` I would only replace filter with find to return only the index only

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as the predicate for `.findIndex()`.

```js
const languages = ["en", "es"];
const path = "http://www.app.name.local/es/compass/sample-compass/compass-temporal";

const getLanguageCodeIndexPosition = () => path.split('/').findIndex(t => languages.includes(t));

console.log( getLanguageCodeIndexPosition() );
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, the position of `es` in the tokens obtained from applying `split` to path in this case is 3

`[ 'http:', '', 'www.app.name.local', 'es', 'compass', 'sample-compass', 'compass-temporal' ]`

Comment: @user615274 Yes, I just was verifying that you wanted `3` as a result. When you refer to the pieces as "tokens", I would've thought you wanted the pieces at the *end* of the URL. But I was just making sure.